# Python, 3D-matrix, how to get an entire column for example?

Tags: python

Currently I have a 3-D matrix looking like this:

```
matrix = [[[28.65626597  8.17721385]
  [54.64450526 49.28804678]]

 [[26.27605202  9.86828489]
  [57.57351335 44.13372456]]

 [[20.81210763 14.8174721 ]
  [52.33518078 37.04860545]]]
```

I would like to get all the first elements, that would be, for example:

```
[28.65626597, 26.27605202, 20,81210763]
```

My question is, is there by chance a way for me to get all those elements without using for-loops?

Comment: Maybe I should've added that I plan to use numpys solver after this, now that I get to think about it, is it possible to use the linalg.solver for an overdetermined system with the help of lambda ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[i[0] for i in [j[0] for j in [list1, list2, list3, list4]]]
```

Comment: That works, what I kind of want to do is to get four of these "lists", that would be:
list1 = [28.65626597, 26.27605202, 20,81210763]
list2 = [8.177, 9.868, 14.817]
list3 = [..]
list4 = [...]
Then I want to use the linalg solver for every single one of these lists, I have another matrix with players, so I kinda want to solve an overdetermined system, is there a way to get all these 4 lists in my example, and then use the linalg solver without any for-loops?

Comment: The problem is that it's not neccesary that my matrix have exactly those dimensions, which means that I could potentially need more lists depending on what some variables are, therefore I need something that doesnt explicitly use four lists, more like I need it to be going through my matrix in the way I described before

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array(matrix)
l1 = mat[:,0,0])
l2 = mat[:,0,1])
l3 = mat[:,1,0])
l4 = mat[:,1,1])
```

Output:

```
[28.65626597 26.27605202 20.81210763]
[ 8.17721385  9.86828489 14.8174721 ]
[54.64450526 57.57351335 52.33518078]
[49.28804678 44.13372456 37.04860545]
```

Comment: thanks for the response, look at my response to the one below you, is there a way to implement that?

Comment: @JanErst I have edited my answer accordingly. Hope it helps!

Comment: that seems to work, but I need to make my code more general, it should also work if this matrix was larger for example, the same way of thinking though

Comment: I have a matrix lookling like:
matrix2 = [1,0,0], [1 1 0], [1,1,1], .., and I want to use the linalg solver on the matrices you just generated